# UnmanagedExportLibrary VisualStudio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm using the UnmanagedExportLibrary template and it has bee working perfectly.  I can use all my .NET Components from my Clarion for WIndows Applications.  Excellent..

Problem:  I have installed Visual Studio 2012 because I now allso use Team Foundation Server 2012.  And of course becase VS2012 seams much bether than the previous editions...  Anyway, when moving to VS2012 I get an error when compiling the solution saying:

```
ILDasm: calling 'ildasm.exe' with /quoteallnames /unicode /nobar /linenum "/out:C:\Users\omheien.S27\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8E0D\UnmanagedExportLibrary1.il" "D:\Data\Annet\Test\UnmanagedExportLibrary1\UnmanagedExportLibrary1\bin\Debug\UnmanagedExportLibrary1.dll"
D:\Data\Annet\Test\UnmanagedExportLibrary1\UnmanagedExportLibrary1\DllExport\RGiesecke.DllExport.targets(8,5): error : Systemet finner ikke angitt fil
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

"Systemet finner ikke filen" meens "System can not find the file"
```

What is causing this ?

Comment: Found the problem.  It seems like Visual Studio 2012 doesnt know ILDASM.EXE.  I added the PATH to ildasm.exe in the system's PATH and now everyting Works just fine..

Comment: Great to know.. will probably be upgrading to VS2012 myself soon.  Another common problem that nobody seems to have stated outright is  using AnyCPU instead of x86 or x64. Using AnyCPU doesn't work for me at all.